# Should I be storing my factories as a property on Global_asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

On:

```
 public class Global_asax : HttpApplication
```

I have a property

```
public GlobalFactoryManager Factories { get; private set; }
```

which I initialise in

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            this.Factories = new GlobalFactoryManager();
        }
```

And try and call in code to get an instance of some type:

```
var staffMember = GlobalContext.Factories().Crm.People.MakeIndividualWithAddedState();
```

Trouble is multiple instances  of HttpApplication get created and the method call above throws an exception because the instance being referred to has null Factory property.  i.e. Application Start only gets called once so it's a lottery as to which instance gets a Factories !=null.

So should factories be stored on Global? They are not holding data just creating types. If not where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application_Start` gets called once per lifetime of the application. The method you are looking for is the `Application_Init`, which gets called for every instance of the Application object created. More info is available from the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (scroll down to the second paragraph: LifeCycle and Global.asax).

As the docs specify, in the `Application_Start` event you should only instantiate static properties, which will then be available to all instances.

Given that your Factory is just providing instances and does not have problems if accessed by multiple threads, I would declare that as a static:

```
public static GlobalFactoryManager Factories { get; private set; }
```

If having a Factories instance shared by all your pages is a problem, then put your initialization into the `Application_Init()` method.